# Brevity of denoting Conjugate[]

Tags: keyboard

How do I make Conjugate[] expressions have a bar above them instead of Conjugate[ before them, in order to shorted up expressions? I'm looking at something like this screenshot for example:
[image]

Comment: `TraditionalForm`?

Comment: If you just need to display the result (and not work further with it) : `yourexpression /. Conjugate -> OverBar`

Comment: or `yourexpression /. Conjugate[x_] -> OverBar@Pane@x` to get more space between the bar and the expression

Comment: If you use David Park's *Presentations* add on (http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html), the command `ComplexConjugateDisplay[True]` will automatically cause the overbar to appear in output for conjugates.

Comment: Building on the two above comments, if you want to do this automatically while further processing your expression (a replacement by `/.` would actually change it), you can teach Mathematica to pretty print `Conjugate` in output for you using: `ClearAttributes[Conjugate, Protected];
Format[Conjugate[x_]] := OverBar@Pane@x;
SetAttributes[Conjugate, Protected];`

Comment: @TheVee that's great, you should turn that into an answer